Pheromones in humans as indicators of desire of mating and how to identify them in the bloodstream / plasma / marrow
I'm writing a story. In this world people need scenting regularly (with the release of pheromones via airborne and as a fine sweat layer on the skin which needs to be rubbed on the other person's skin), this as a basic human need to be healthy and also (but not always) as a precursor of mating.
I would like to know which kind of test (blood test, urine test, bone marrow test) will be best to find certain hormone in the human body. That hormone will show that a person wanted to mate.
This is to have legal confirmation if a person in a position of power might have abused that power. Those tests are not done just because to "confirm" if they're in love not, they're just done when certain circumstances happens and might require legal action.
I'm not a scientist, doctor, lab analyst or lab technician, I'm just making poor researches in the internet and adapting as I see fit.
I learned a bit that pheromones are kinda like hormones (because humans don't release pheromones, in any case... there's a controversy over there that I'm aware of it but I don't need it for my story).
Also this people in my story, the whole population are not realistic humans, they're humans but leaning a lot in animal behavior. Like hybrids... but they don't have ears and tails, they're humans in the outside and maybe a bit of animalistic in the inside.
I learned about hormones an emotions:

Cortisol: The stress responder
Serotonin: The mood stabilizer
Oxytocin: The love and bonding hormone
Estrogen and Testosterone: The sex hormone duo
Dopamine: The pleasure and reward neurotransmitter

I think Oxytocin could be the hormone I need in my story to have that confirmation, that will show that a person wanted to mate
And I was looking how oxytocin could be found in the bloodstream? plasma? urine? but I read a very scientific paper that I didn't understand and at the end of it, they say they didn't know :D
So, I was thinking, maybe pheromones elicit a response for the human, making them release their own pheromones to mirror the other and kinda have a courtship dance... their pheromones mingle and they indicate if the partner is 100% compatible or not (maybe less than 40% makes them a very incompatible partner, or more like not a parter)
And if they're like 90%+ compatible they feel the need to mark the other with a bite in the neck, lol.
I imagine, if the human is excited and wants to mark the other is because they want to mate. So their bloodstream / urine / marrow bone will have all those hormones flowing there, the specific hormone of Oxytocin.
So people will got to get their blood / urine / marrow bone tested and the results will show oxytocin (or I might invent some other hormone, like "markytocin" xD), meaning that person had the desire to mate. It could be like how alcohol stores in the bloodstream for some hours and then the body absorbs it or expels it (is oxytocin expelled?)
I know I can invent everything I want... but I think it would be fun to have like a scientific base on how to find the markytocin in the body to indicate that person wanted to mate. And that test can be used in court, to show that person wanted to mate that other person, not matter if the other person is already married... or claimed... and start a divorce process or a lawsuit.
So, I was thinking:

Markytocin is concentrated in the urine, like alcohol, and it can be find with a urine test, indicating the person wanted to mate 12-24 hours earlier. If the test is made in the next 2 days, it will show nothing.
Or Markytocin is concentrated in the bloodstream, a blood test can show it.
Markytocin is concentrated in plasma, a plasma test can show it.
Markytocin is concentrated in the bone marrow, this is a most difficult test to make (as opposed of an urine test) and maybe it has more accuracy...

What would you think? If you're a lab analyst or technician, does this look kinda realistic to you? Thank you so much for your attention.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What you really need is an emergency introductory remedial course in human physiology. After getting a basic understanding of what hormones are and how they work then you may want to come back and edit this question. The thing which I don't understand at all is what's the purpose of all those blood tests? Normal people can easily tell when they are in love with no need for "scientific" confirmation. Can you imagine the dialogue? "But, doctor, she leaves me cold." "Nevertheless, sir, this here computer printout says you are in love to your ears. Trust the science, sir!"

@AlexP better yet how does the sicentist know which human triggered the response, maybe they are secretly in love with the nurse taking the blood.

English is my second language, I can edit for clarifying, maybe I used the wrong tag. How come other people get amazing responses playing with worldbuilding and I get this? I said I'm not a doctor, I googled about chemicals in the bloodstream, but should I read complete books on a career that take years to complete, when I just have a hazy idea and I came here to ask for guidance? Did you both rise your points by commenting on posts you don't personally like and don't understand? What kind of contributors do that? You could just not comment anything at all and pass this post.

@AudreyG Thanks for the tick, I'd not finished editing to explain the limitations of the test. Please also be aware that we ask that 24 to 48 hours go by to allow others to answer before the tick is awarded. You can withdraw and re-award it at any time if you wish.

@Escapeddentalpatient. I'm so sorry, I didn't know the etiquette, omg, I withdrawn it and I'll wait for the 24-48 window to pass, but I'll assure you: I'll re-award it to you :D

I've just had a thought, I'll add it to my answer.

do the humans want to mate? is there blood in theire blood test, yes, then they want to mate.

I would like to add one important fact. Hormones, or even a woman being wet of a man having an erection, are not definitive conclusions that someone wants sex. At best it gives the readiness of the body for a mating. The mind might not want it. See rape victims, whether man or women, where the body can respond with readiness and orgasms even though the mind definitely is opposed to the mating. To avoid any difficulties with this you should very explicitly state that if the hormones are found, the mind is always ok with in for your human like creatures.

Luteinizing Hormone.
This is directly related to desire to mate in its most immediate form - it signals sexual desire (or recent sexual desire).
It's detectable in saliva, and the blood serum levels correspond to saliva levels directly, which is handy - a simple swab of the inside of the cheek or beneath the tongue to pick up spit.
Note:
It's presence in human females varies cyclically with the ovulation cycle, the peak concentration being at the time of ovulation. There is significant evidence that stimulation, which causes the release of the hormone can provoke immediate ovulation if at the right part of the cycle.
To distinguish between ovulation phase and sexual desire, the levels of other hormones would need to be measured and judged as to their correspondence with that timing within the cycle - this leads to a need for different tests for male and female.
It also leads to a significant error rate just from individual variation in hormone levels, and uncertainty in female results if ovulation is taking place.
Note 2:
Variability in oral health can affect the results. Maybe there's even a plant to chew on in your world that masks or confuses things.
(May or may not be useful: It's present in pregnancy at lower levels, the presence of hCT (human Chorionic Gonadotropin) would be released in the presence of a fetus to suppress LH.)
Note 3:
In principle, there's no reason why detector couldn't be implanted into a Bluetooth equivalent device and couldn't be implanted into a tooth filling (yeah, Blueteeth!). This could be powered by an external magnetic field much like the supermarket security tags are powered by the big loops at the exit. This would allow for easy screening without risk of getting bitten by an uncooperative subject. Can be combined with ID chip or even personal banking/purchase capability and a GPS record of movements.

xD xD Thank you so much!!! This is exactly what I needed!! Thank you so much for your kindness!! :D :D I also upvoted your answer but it doesn't show because I don't have the points, lol
I'll read this info and adapt it to my story, I understand it It can lead to a significant error rate, but I'll fix that in my world xD

There are a few ways you can go with this. If the pheromones are airborne, you could have a sniffer that determines if anyone in the area is in that state. If not, you say it's a skin-to-skin thing, so swabbing the skin should readily identify if the person is "secreting".
If you really want to go all blood-testy, then you'll want to look for precursor hormones. Consider the case of food. In the presence of food, we salivate, but you don't want to check for saliva to see if someone's starving. If you want to check the blood for someone who is hungry, you'd look for leptin or ghrelin. With thyroid, we don't look for T4 or T3, we look for thyroid stimulating hormone (TSH). There are many, many blood tests that work that way.
Since these are aliens you'll want to make up your own chemical names. I'd be surprised if there are five people on this exchange who could spot oxytocin in a lineup so you're good to come up with technobabble here.

xD That's what I read in that scientific paper, lol!! I chose oxytocin because of its "bonding" properties, & that paper said "since we're not in agreement what is oxytocin and what is vasopressin, then what are we doing here man" & then I was lost... But thank you so much for your contribution!! It makes me see more clearly the thing I wanted, I'll take your suggestions into account!! :D

Hormones produce secondary effects on the body which can be identified by other members of the species. There is no need for a blood test. Humans have a number of such effects including certain behaviors. (Professionals have learned that doing certain behaviors which emulate "ready to mate" can cause young males to give them a lot of money.) Some of the effects are a bit subtle and we can react to them without realizing what we are reacting to.
For purposes of a story involving humans and mating, it would be very important that the hormone and detection be able to be done by those who have no access to labs or western medical systems. Otherwise, the lack of mating would cause population problems.

:D OH! I see where's the problem, lol... This is a world where they're not human/human, but if I said humanoid, people will think in Long Man... what's his name, Slender Man! ........ They're human with some internal animal traits, I'll invent a name for them. I'll edit the post, I'm sorry for not being clear. Yet that's not where I'm going, my story is not about population problems, however, thank you so much for your contribution!! :D

@AudreyG Baboons have estrus swellings clearly identifying when to mate. Many grass eating animals do a flehmen action to transfer pheromones indicating when to mate to a special scent organ. If you include an organ to detect such scents, then these individuals would not need a lab.

The idea I was trying to make is: if a person is suspect of driving drunk, they would be asked for some test to confirm or clear that assumption. I was looking for some ideas about a test or lab applied to a person suspected of mating someone when they shouldn't for, you know, worldbuilding, and your comment is "don't need a lab". Your suggestions look fine for pistilverse, but my story is not pistilverse, however, thank you for your time.
